# Determining the value of a function scope

Tags: javascript, function, scope

Can someone explain to me how the answer is 15? I understand the function scope of doSomething is calling doSomethingElse, but I am getting a different result than 15.

```
function doSomething(a) {
    b = a + doSomethingElse( a * 2 );

    console.log( b * 3 );
}

function doSomethingElse(a) {
    return a - 1;
}

var b;

doSomething( 2 ); //15
```

Comment: What result are you getting? I'm getting 15 when I try it.

Comment: I am getting 18. How did you get 15?

Comment: step by step is below @pat

Comment: The step by step below is also returning 15. Opening console and copy/pasting your code returns 15.

Answer (score 1):

There's no scope involved here. Nothing in any of those vars would be crossing a scope boundary:

```
1. doSomething(2);
2. b = 2 + doSomethingElse(2 * 2);
3. b = 2 + (2 * 2 - 1);
4. b = 2 + 3
5. b = 5;
6. console.log(b * 3);
7. console.log(5 * 3);
8. console.log(15);
9. 15
```

Comment: A scope specifies a domain in which a variable or a group of variables (or functions, or objects) has value.  So a scope by itself doesn't have a value exactly, nor is it correct to say that "the scope of doSomething() is calling doSomethingElse()."  And yes to Marc's comment, doSomething() and doSomethingElse are both in the same scope: global.